# Кнопка прокрутки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

делаю кнопки прокрутки страницы:

> ```
> $(document).on('click','#down',function(e){
>   document.body.scrollTop += 50;
> })
> ```

в опере и firefox такой код работает, а в хроме нет. Как сделать это кроссбраузерно?

Comment: [работает в chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/jwzU3/) у вас наверное несколько элементов с id down

Comment: нет, только один. я же говорю - в опере работает

Comment: я же говорю, работает в хроме, где-то в  другом месте ошибка.

Comment: я понял, как бы её найти?

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).on("click", '#nav', function(event) {
  var height0 = 400;
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: height0
  }, 800);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="nav">nav</button>

<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br> 1
<br>
```

Необходимую высоту height0 вычислять.

Comment: так не работает почему-то

Comment: все работает, однако..

Comment: на jsfiddle работает, но у меня на сайте почему-то не работает